Tkinter - resize the window from a different angle
when a window in Tkinter is resized,
(in my instance by resizing an image that in the Tkinter's top level window with dynamic size)
the new position is the made by taking the original top left position and from there expanding from it, to the bottom and rightward sides of the screen based on the window's new width and height values. Easier explanation (top left will still be top left).
so I'm curious if you can change this method and expand the window's height and width from a different angle / point  - (bottom right, etc.)

Do you mean that using geometry() to resize the window programmically?

pretty much, if that is possible, so it can be a nice solution. - but I meant the bigger picture; make the window somehow resize programmically -> from other sides / constant points or angles

I don't understand what is the problem. If you know top-left and width-height at start then you can calculate bottom-right (at start) and later use it to calculate new top-left  like top = bottom - new_height left = right - new_width and you can move window to new top-left

or if you know old_width and new_width then you have to move left to position new_left = left - (old_width - new_width). And similarly you have do for top.

and in similar way you can do it for center point - find center point at start and later use it to calculate top-left (using width/2, height/2) and move window

If you pack the widgets to the right/bottom sides, instead of the left/top, then they'll "stick" to the SE corner and the other widgets will "pull away" from the NW corner.  Programmatically?  Unpack and pack again, I guess.  Put frames around groups of widgets to make the shuffling easier.  Don't need to calculate positions, let Tk do that part for you. You could have fun writing a proc to do that for you!
